# How can I remove associated change from a TFS build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to remove the associated change below (commit `fb6916d`) from this build?
I have consulted the documentation for the TFS web API, but it only told me [how to list associated changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and not how to remove them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Associated changes**: it shows the different commits between current and previous build.

**Work items linked to associated changes**: it shows the work items related to associated commits.

One addition, if you have non-successful builds, (failed or partially succeeded), the commits will keep showing up. The commits are calculated to compare against the last fully successful build.

It's by designed. Sorry, not be able to remove them if there are different commits compared with previous build.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case, but thanks for confirming my suspicions.